# Possible for parent process to HANG on "wait" step if child process becomes a ZOMBIE or CRASHES?

Tags: c

I have used pipe / fork etc to execv to execute a subprocess in C and it is working 100%.

Essentially I have the following WAIT step in the parents code:

```
wait(&rv); //where rv is just an int of zero
```

My question is: is it possible for the parent to wait "indefinitely" or HANG if the child crashes with a segmentation fault or becomes a zombie?

Put another way, if the child code has no "endless loops" etc....is it still possible for the parent process to just "hang" forever of the wait step?

What is the safest approach here to prevent handing? I have seen a WNOHANG....should I be using that? But I need to wait for the sub process to end before continuing?

```
waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)
```

Also, is it best practice to use a SIGCHLD handler?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a zombie child process (either by segmentation fault or normal exit), wait will return its exit status. If there are no zombie children, wait will hang if there is at least one running child, but will not hang if there's no children. In the latter case it will return -1 and set `errno = ECHILD`.

You might wish to use `waitpid` if you want to wait for a specific child, but it sounds like you don't need `WNOHANG`.

A `SIGCHLD` handler could be useful to signal that a call to `wait` will not hang, but otherwise is not needed. If you don't want to care about whether your children are running or not, you can set `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`. Then no zombies will be generated.