# Why does asynchronous child become a zombie altough parent waits for it?

Tags: bash, signals

I use the following code to start some long running task asynchronously but detect if it fails at the very beginning:

```
sleep 0.3 &
long_running &
wait -n
# [Error handling]

# Do other stuff.

# Wait for completion of 'long_running'.
wait -n
# [Error handling]
```

If I SIGINT (using Ctrl+C) the script during waiting for the long running child, the long running task just continues and gets a zombie after completion.
Furthermore the parent script consumes full CPU. I have to SIGKILL the parent to get rid of the processes.

I know that SIGINT is [ignored by the child](https://gist.github.com/doak/08b69c500c91a7fade9f2c61882c93b4#file-test-signal-handling-for-asynchron-child-sh-L42) (which is probably the reason it continues till completion), **but why does the parent get into such confusing state?**
It works (like expected) if I kill the child when SIGINT has been received (the commented `trap` below), but I want to understand why it does not work the other way.

Below is the complete script. Please refer also to https://gist.github.com/doak/08b69c500c91a7fade9f2c61882c93b4 for an even more complete example/try-out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count="count=100000"  # Adapt that 'dd' lasts about 3s. Comment out to run forever.
#fail=YES  # Demonstrates failure of background task.

# This would work.
#trap "jobs -p | xargs kill" SIGINT

echo executing long running asynchronous task ...
sleep 0.3 &
dd if=/dev/zero$fail of=/dev/null bs=1M $count &
wait -n
errcode=$?
if test $errcode -ne -0; then
    echo "failed"
    exit $errcode
fi

echo waiting for completion ...
wait -n
errcode=$?
echo finished
exit $errcode
```

It could be that my question is related to this C question, although it discusses the system call `wait()`: [Possible for parent process to HANG on "wait" step if child process becomes a ZOMBIE or CRASHES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938677)

Comment: Interesting question. It should be noted that the Bash `wait` builtin may behave differently than the `wait()` system call referenced in your question.

Comment: @MichaelJaros, that is true, I will clarify the question. Thanks.